# Problem with installing GPU

Tags: graphics, gpu

I installed my GPU two months ago in my computer and everything worked fine. All of a sudden, I noticed in the "Details" page from "System settings" that my GPU is not working anymore; I make sure it didn't work when I tried to play a game that I used to play when the GPU was working.

Anyways, I tried to install the GPU again, the same way I did before, using this page:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

when I go to "additional drivers", I find my GPU there, but when I go to the "Details" page is not there in the "Graphics". Also, the GPU is not working when I play any game that needs the GPU to work well. Any Ideas how to fix it?

It looks like the GPU is installed but not working.

[image]

When I try to use "sudo nvidia-settings" I can't choose NVIDIA.

UPDATE:

This is the additional drivers, where it shows my Nvidia 352 that I want to use.
[image]

But here (In details page), the Nvidia is not shown; so I can't use it:

[image]

Comment: How did you install the graphics driver. If you used `run` files, then you will have to re-install the driver after each kernel update.

Comment: The same way described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Version: 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix:

1.'sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-settings'

2. 'whereis nvidia-settings'
3. Delete everything listed.  Because of a "feature" in Linux the system thinks that your going to need these files again.  What is happening  is thst you config files are not removed.

NOTE TO DEVELOPERS -  Purge means remove EVERYTHING including the config files

4. Then reinstall the driver per instructions.

This is the simplest way, that I found,  to cure most configuration problems.

Comment: I tried this, but still I'm having the same problem. I'm using "Wine" and "PlayOnLinux" maybe that affect it?